# How can I make a button with a backgroundimage that has transparency work?

Tags: c#, button, png, transparency

I created a PNG with a transparent background.  If I set my button control to have that image as a background, I see grey where I should be seeing the form it is set on.  I set BackColor for the button to transparent, but to no avail.

How can I make it work right?

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Is it really sitting directly on the Form?

Comment: WinForms, and the form is empty save for the button.